# Why it always has carousel.less which inherit style code to my bootstrap html code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I use Bootstrap to make a Carousel Side page.
I tried to change the font in .Carousel-Caption.
but the font always with shadow.

I  check the code, i found it came from .carousel.less file.
I do not have it in my CSS folder. how can i stop it or solve this issues.

Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPWNT.png)

Comment: What's file you use on the page: bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css? Do you have an CSS minifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) Bootstrap precompiled files. Set values of LESS [carousel parameters](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#carousel) and download your custom version of Bootstrap. Use `none` for `@carousel-text-shadow` to remove unwanted shadow.
Also it is possible by including to your page another CSS-file that contains

```
.carousel-caption {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Note, this file must be inclused **after** *bootstrap.css* (or *bootstrap.min.css*) to overwrite Bootstrap styles. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css"/>
```

But the first way is prefer.